# Upgrade 20.04.5 to 22.04.1 ... software updater doesn't see new release, do-release-upgrade fails

Tags: upgrade, 22.04, do-release-upgrade

- I'm on 20.04.5.
- My other two 20.04.5 machines notified of 22.04.1 release.
- This machine does not indicate an upgrade available no matter how many times I open Software Updater.
- If I do `sudo do-release-upgrade` I get `Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts.` etc.
- If I try `https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts` in the browser,
  the browser does find that page.

What is going on, please?

Comment: Before anything else make sure the system is fully updated. You may want to use `sudo apt full-upgrade` instead of the usual "upgrade".

Comment: Remember to run `sudo apt update` to update package-database before running `sudo apt full-upgrade`!!

Comment: I tried your suggestions but the result is the same:
```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts. Check your Internet connection or proxy settings
There is no development version of an LTS available.
To upgrade to the latest non-LTS development release 
set Prompt=normal in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.
```

Comment: The error message you posted says you used the -d option so it is correct. Do not use the -d Ubuntu 22.04 is in full release.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.
There's always been something weird about my cert setup.
So I had an alias I always used in my user account:

```
alias certs='export SSL_CERT_FILE=$(python3 -c "import certifi; print(certifi.where())")'
```

I executed that in a root session and now do-release-upgrade is able to connect!